# how do I overwrite the opcodes 8b5508 with 909090 at address 0xaaaa using this?

Tags: objective-c, c, intel, code-injection, opcode

I've been doing hours of research which brought me to mach override: http://guiheneuf.org/mach%20inject%20for%20intel.html

I'm trying to rewrite the opcode 8b5508 at the given address in my target with nops (909090). I think mach override seems to be the solution, but I have no idea how to use it... has anybody got any advice? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any other context, this seems like a textbook problem. If you're using C, you could do it this way:

```
char *myptr = my_given_addr;
myptr[0] = 0x90;
myptr[1] = 0x90;
myptr[2] = 0x90;
```

There's probably a more elegant solution but this gets the general gist. I'm new to SO... is there a homework tag?

Comment: just note that on any system that has DEP or some of of memory page protection, that will likely explode unless you enbale write access